# Sort queries by id and name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, but I'll do my best. I have two tables that look like this...

```
id | firstname | lastname
---+-----------+---------
 1 | JD        | Gonzo
 2 | Mike      | Bryan
 etc
```

The other is like this

```
id | staffid | business
---+---------+---------
 1 |    1    | a
 2 |    4    | a
 etc
```

I would like to query the staffid's of the second table, then get their names from the first table and order the results according to the firstname of the first table. I'm not sure how to go about this, but I have thought about just adding the names to the second table then ordering the query according to the names, but I was hoping that there would be a better method for doing this. Thanks in advance for your help. I'm still kind of new to databasing. By the way, I'm using PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming staffid is a foreign key,

`SELECT table2.staffid, table1.firstname FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.staffid = table1.id ORDER BY firstname`

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. I never thought about this. I've been storing arrays of id's in my tables and then just iterating over them to find the info. This is going to work SSOOOOOOO much better. Love it... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You select statement should look something like this

```
$sql =  "SELECT table1.firstname AS firstname, table1.lastname AS lastname 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.staffid == table1.id 
ORDER BY table1.firstname ASC";
```